# Facebook messenger api send video message

Tags: javascript, facebook, video, messenger, facebook-chat

Is it possible to use Facebook's new messenger API to send a video message?

I tried it using this code:

```
function sendVideo(sender)
messageData = {
            "attachment":{
                "type":'video',
                "payload":{
                    "url":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/v/t35.0-12/12986901_10156932107880294_1613469135_o.jpg?oh=096aca0f851bd58ee11959982cba1f0d&oe=57114D35"
                }       
            }
        }
    request({
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
        qs: {access_token:token},
        method: 'POST',
        json: {
        recipient: {id:sender},
            message: messageData,
            }
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
        console.log('Error sending message: ', error);
        } else if (response.body.error) {
        console.log('Error: ', response.body.error);
        }
    });
 }
```

But by printing logs, I got the following error:

```
Error:  { message: '(#2) Temporary send message failure. Please try again later',
2016-04-14T06:11:39.509376+00:00 app[web.1]:   type: 'OAuthException',
2016-04-14T06:11:39.509377+00:00 app[web.1]:   is_transient: true,
2016-04-14T06:11:39.509378+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 2,
2016-04-14T06:11:39.509379+00:00 app[web.1]:   fbtrace_id: 'GsTH+2P70rB' }
```

Thanks!

Comment: It states int the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference) that the `type` parameter can only be of type `image` or `attachment` so I would say that video is not available.

Answer (score 0):

As per Messenger Documentation Its possible Type of attachment, may be image or template.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference